# GreenDAO on Android: Byte Array as Primary Key / Building Query Containing Where Clause on Byte Array Property

Tags: android, sqlite, arrays, where-clause, greendao

I am currently trying to select entries using a query containing a where condition on a (byte array) property. This property/column contains a serialized UUID. Unfortunately I currently cannot change the data type of this column, as the database is created and synced by a separate module which only works properly with the current implementation. As greenDao cannot handle byte arrays as primary keys properly I am trying to work around this issue somehow. Creating my own selection queries etc. would be a solution
The property is defined during greenDAO generation as:

```
Entity randomEntity = schema.addEntity("RandomEntity");
...
randomEntity.addByteArrayProperty("RandomProperty");
```

The query is built using following line:

```
Query query = this.mRandomEntityDao.queryBuilder().where(RandomEntityDao.Properties.RandomProperty.eq(randomByteArray)).build();
```

Unfortunately I get following error with this operation:

```
de.greenrobot.dao.DaoException: Illegal value: found array, but simple object required
at de.greenrobot.dao.query.WhereCondition$PropertyCondition.checkValueForType(WhereCondition.java:75)
...
```

**Is this where condition is simply not supported by greenDAO or am I missing something crucial?** Unfortunately I cannot use another datatype for this certain property.

**Edit:**

My current workaround goes as follows:
As greenDao can handle primary keys which are strings (up to a certain point) and UUIDs can also be represented by this data type I altered the existing tables and added following columns:

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'RANDOMTABLE' ADD COLUMN '_GREENID' TEXT;");
```

The sync module is ignoring this column so there shouldn’t be any issues with that. Then I created a trigger mapping the serialized UUID in the `ID` column to the new `_GREENID` column:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER randomtableGreen AFTER INSERT ON 'RANDOMTABLE' BEGIN " + 
"UPDATE 'RANDOMTABLE' SET '_GREENID' = HEX(NEW.ID) WHERE 'RANDOMTABLE'.ID = NEW.ID; " +
"END;");
```

Finally I run an update on the table in case they already contained some entries prior to the creation of the trigger:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE 'RANDOMTABLE' SET '_GREENID' = HEX(ID) WHERE '_GREENID' <> '';");
```

Comment: What do you store in this column and how many bytes approximately per row-entry? Why can't you use another datatype?

Comment: I have updated my question properly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About byte[] aka BLOB in greendao:**

Looking at `de.greenrobot.dao.query.WhereCondition.PropertyCondition.checkValueForType` conditions for `byte[]` are not supported at the moment, because the following lines will always throw an exception if value is of type `byte[]`.

```
if (value != null && value.getClass().isArray()) {
    throw new DaoException("Illegal value: found array, but simple object required");
}
```

**Solution 1 - modify and contribute to greendao:**

You could modify the uper lines, so that the exception is only thrown if the type of value and the type of the Property don't fit.

```
if (value != null) {
    if (value.getClass().isArray() && !property.type.isArray()) {
        throw new DaoException("Illegal value: found array, but " +
                "simple object required");
    }
    if (!value.getClass().isArray() && property.type.isArray()) {
        throw new DaoException("Illegal value: found simple object, " +
                "but array required");
    }
}
```

Maybe this will already solve the problem, but there may be other parts in greendao stopping to work with this edit or that will break the query. For example the binding of parameters to queries may not work with arrays.

**Solutinon 2 - Use `queryRaw(String where, String... selectionArg)`**

This is pretty straight forward and shouldn't be a problem with some knowledge about SQLite.

**Solution 3 - Using a lookup-table**

Assume the original table:

```
ORIG
-------------------------------
UUID     BLOB
...
```

You can modify `ORIG` and add a autoincrement-primarykey:

```
db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'ORIG' " +
        "ADD COLUMN 'REF_ID' INT PRIMARYKEY AUTOINCREMENT;");
```

The sync service should already take care about the uniqueness of `ORIG.UUID` and ignore the new `ORIG.REF_ID`-column. For inserting new UUIDs the sync service will probably use `INSERT` causing a new autoincremented value in `ORIG.REF_ID`.
For updating an existing `UUID` the sync service will probably use `UPDATE ... WHERE UUID=?` and no new `ORIG.REF_ID`-value will be created, but the old value will be kept.

Summarized the `ORIG`-table has a new Bijection between column `REF_ID` and column `UUID`.

Now you can create another table:

```
ORIG_IDX
------------------------------
UUID      TEXT PRIMARYKEY
REF_ID    INT  UNIQUE
```

(If your data is smaller than 8 bytes it will also fit into a `INT` instead `TEXT`, but I don't know if there is a built-in cast/coversion from `BLOB` to `INT`.)

`ORIG.IDX.UUID` will be the String-representation of `ORIG.UUID`.
`ORIG_IDX.REF_ID` is foreign key for `ORIG.REF_ID`.

`ORIG_IDX` is filled and updated by triggers:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER T_ORIG_AI AFTER INSERT ON 'ORIG' BEGIN " + 
        "INSERT 'ORIG_IDX' SET 'REF_ID' = NEW.REF_ID, 'UUID' = NEW.UUID" +
        "END;");
```

Create corresponding triggers for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.

You can create the tables `ORIG` and `ORIG_IDX` using greendao and then query a requested uuid with:

```
public Orig getOrig(String uuid) {
    OrigIdx origIdx = OrigIdxDao.queryBuilder().where(
            QrigIdxDao.Properties.UUID.eq(uuid)).unique();
    if (origIdx != null) {
        return origIdx.getOrig();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I think String-primarykey is not supported yet, so `dao.load(uuid)` won't be available.

**CONCERING AN EXTENDED TABLE:**

You could use a `string` primarykey-column and provide conversion-methods in the keep-sections of your entity. You will have to compute the primarykey-column before you do an insert.

If there are other tools inserting data (for example your sync service) you'd have to use a trigger to compute your primary-key before the insert happens. This doesn't seem possible using SQLite. Thus the primarykey-constraint will fail on inserts by the sync service, so this solution will not work with primarykey!

Comment: I'll give raw queries a go as I'm hesitant to change something in the greenDAO code (but as a last resort I will also try this option).

Comment: I find your answer regarding the reference table very intriguing and I’ll give it a try. There is only one thing I want to note:  The ‘_GREENID’ column is not automatically incremented by greenDAO. This is also true for the ‘ID’ column which is not automatically incremented by the sync module. Their uniqueness should be ensured by using UUIDs as their values (whereas a 1:1 mapping between both columns of an entry should exist). But - I can see the issue of adding rows via the sync service and accessing the entries prior to the update of the trigger.

Comment: You can make the UUID-column unique and add a primarykey-autoincrement-column. Depending on the logic of your sync service this shouldn't cause problems (as the syncservice should care about the uniqueness and update rows if the UUID is already present). Then you can use the toOneMapping of my post. If your sync service doesn't care about updating but inserts everything the primarykey-autoincrement you will have to care about UUID-uniquness in your TRIGGERs.